# Rendering result different between Path tracing and branched path tracing

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

In path tracing with 10000 samples i have this result:

[image: path tracing]

With the branched path tracing at 10000 AA samples and diffuse, glossy, transmission.. at 1 i have this result:

[image: branched path tracing]

nothing else has changed.
Why this difference?

Comment: maybe upload the blend file?

Comment: AA samples are Anti-aliasing - having diffuse, glossy, transmission.. at 1 will give a different result to 10000 render samples in non-branching.

Comment: Maybe it's related to what Thomas Dinges recently posted. https://developer.blender.org/rB99e20d7b8930479edfacae246a529e03b84264ae

It's says that for multiple lights, the lights were being selected randomly for the indirect component.  If this was your issue then it should be fixed now.